# How can a floating-point number be printed with more precision?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision, primitive-types

So i was attempting to code this question [Link](https://codeforces.com/contest/492/problem/B) and i developed the logic and i started coding it. The code is shown below, but there is an issue with it. When i gave the code the following input (Image 1), the output came out to be 2.22582e+007, whereas the correct accepted output is 22258199.500000. What changes should i make in the data type to amend this error. How can i change the notation. Please bear with me as my knowledge of data types is limited.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,l;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> l;
    vector<float> v;
    vector<float> b;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    if(v[0]!=0){
        b.push_back(v[0]);
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            b.push_back((v[i] - v[i-1])/2.0);
        }
    }else if(v[0] == 0){
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            b.push_back((v[i] - v[i-1])/2.0);
        }
    }
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());
    cout << b[b.size()-1];
}
```

[image: Code output]

Comment: You can also read up on pretty printing using `iomanip`

Comment: And unless you're talking to a vector processor, such as a GPU, you probably want to use `double` instead of `float` by default.

Comment: fyi: `b[b.size()-1]` is the same as `b.back()`.

Comment: Talk a look at this, it may solve your problem
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed
and
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: This might be a print out issue. What you may wanna look out for is [std::precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) which allows you to specify the parameters for a print type.

Comment: int64_t is the maximum supported by the standard, some compilers have a 128 variant

Comment: @K.Kiryu I think this is probably it, i will look into it.

Comment: FWIW, what exactly do you mean with the "precision of an integer" while you are in fact using floats?

Comment: I wanted to change the notation, not the precision, i will edit it so that it does not cause any confusion.

Comment: The issue is the precision with which the result is formatted, not the precision of integers in C++ nor the format used (the judge accepts both `fixed` and `scientific` notation).

Comment: Some additional notes: (a) The problem is ill-specified as it posits integer inputs without specifying any limits, resulting in a programmer not knowing what C++ integer type might suffice. (b) There is no need to use the vector `b` or to sort it. It suffices merely to find the maximum distance, which can be done with a single remembered maximum distance which is updated as each interval is checked. (c) The code in the question accounts for a possible interval between 0 and the first lantern but fails to account for a possible interval between the last lantern and *l*.

Comment: (d) As the only possible fraction involved is .5, floating-point could be avoided entirely simply by working in units of half-steps (if the distance between two lamps is 5, the light must extend a distance of 5 half steps) and then, when printing the maximum, print `maximum/2` for the integer portion and print “.5” if `maximum` is an odd number of half steps.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil noted and I agree on the all the points, especially (c). I debugged it afterwards. Also, I pondered upon the iterative maximum way of doing this question, but this code was a naive way of doing things as I just did what came to my mind first and did not gave it any thought. But thanks for the points and correction. Happy that you invested your time for my silly problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10)` to output the value in a round-trippable format. (This will need headers `<limits>` and `<iomanip>`).

If that doesn't work, try also replacing `float` with `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use `iomanip`.

```
#inlcude <iomanip>

cout<<fixed<<setprecision(6)
```

`fixed` will disable the scientific notation.

`setprecision` will allow you to be as precise as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue.
[link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)
The issue primarily was that the  notation of the output was scientific and sometimes the online judges do not accept that, hence to change the notation from scientific to fixed and to other forms, the following code snippet can be used.
Either you can increase the precision or you can change the notation. Either of the latter cases can help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "The number 0.01 in fixed:      " << std::fixed << 0.01 << 
'\n'
              << "The number 0.01 in scientific: " << std::scientific << 
0.01 << '\n'
              << "The number 0.01 in hexfloat:   " << std::hexfloat << 0.01 
<< '\n'
              << "The number 0.01 in default:    " << std::defaultfloat << 
0.01 << '\n';
    double f;
    std::istringstream("0x1P-1022") >> std::hexfloat >> f;
    std::cout << "Parsing 0x1P-1022 as hex gives " << f << '\n';
}
```

[output of the given code - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUCtR.gif)

Comment: This answer says “This” resolved the issue and then shows several different things. It does not tell the reader whether `hexfloat` or `scientific` or something else resolved the issue, nor does it tell the reader what they mean or do. (Links to supplementary information may be useful, but all necessary information should be in the answer, as external links change and break over time.)

Comment: that is why i have provided with the link.

Comment: This answer does not tell the reader which of the different things resolved the problem. This answer does not tell the reader what the things do.

Comment: now fixed. i will keep this in my mind from now on. lost my reputation.

Comment: Sorry, but the edit makes the answer incorrect. The judge does accept scientific notation. (I registered for an account and tested it.) The actual issue was that the result was printed with insufficient precision. When printed with sufficient precision, either scientific or fixed notation is accepted.